# Fetch filter properties from mysql innodb table (about 1.5m rows)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product table and on it has 1.5m rows. I want to get products and filter on it ( about its categories, brands etc)

i do it like that : 
( scenario is that : i enter the category whose id is 35 and i want to fetch its and its subs product)

```
SELECT distinct r_category as r_category,brand as brand,price as price,offer_id FROM Product where Product.status = 1 and Product.r_category IN (35,279,280,274,276,278,277,275,39,294,295,296,38,292,293,290,291,289,34,271,272,273,36,283,282,284,281,37,285,286,288,287,350,351,348,349,4)
```

this code give me what categories and brands and prices they have.

i got products about 0.049 second , but when i run this code its raising to 7 sec.

```
0.14223003387451 first query (with limit 20)


7.0965619087219 last query time ( about 957895 rows)
```

( my table is innodb , and i have indexes r_category, brand,price etc)

Thanks for all

[image: table properties]

[image: table indexes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decrease time of query you can do:

- Add indexes in all columns which you use in where clause (status, r_category in this example)
- Add force `FORCE INDEX(r_category)` -> `SELECT distinct r_category as r_category,brand as brand,price as price,offer_id FROM Product FORCE INDEX(r_category) where Product.status = 1 and Product.r_category IN (35,279,280,274,276,278,277,275,39,294,295,296,38,292,293,290,291,289,34,271,272,273,36,283,282,284,281,37,285,286,288,287,350,351,348,349,4)`

Comment: Sorry i dont understand ur second point. Will i use it like that ?

`SELECT distinct r_category as r_category,brand as brand,price as price,offer_id FROM _product FORCE INDEX(Product.r_category) where _product.status = 1 and _product.r_category IN (35,279,280,274,276,278,277,275,39,294,295,296,38,292,293,290,291,289,34,271,272,273,36,283,282,284,281,37,285,286,288,287,350,351,348,349,4)`

Comment: Yes, only add FORCE INDEX(Product.r_category) and continue with your query.

Comment: there is an error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.r_category) where _product.status = 1 and _product.r_category IN (35,279,280,27' at line 1

Comment: sorry FORCE INDEX(r_category)

Comment: I'am using this method in 10 - 20 million and decreases total time, and this didn't work for you? Weird.. Can you try to force the status?

Comment: Yes, so weird. But i dont know , what can i do for that. How is your servers ? How many ? How is your cache mechanism ?

Comment: Decreasing occurs because of optimization, server is another thing. Maybe because InnoDB uses lot of memory. Same time also at limited queries?

Comment: You mean i change engine InnoDB to MyIsam ? And i cant limit because i should fetch all brands that category has.

Comment: If you know the diference and of course its not productive, give it a try. I have tested this in MyIsam and NdbCluster.

Comment: Now i dont have cluster system . But i can try MyIsam . I will and let u know.

Comment: Also change the `SELECT distinct r_category as r_category, ....` with `SELECT r_category,  ...... GROUP BY r_category` and tell me if you see any difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44463/discussion-between-dimimpou-and-muhammet-arslan)

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible paginate your query by limit and offset. There are a lot of memory allocations when you receive 957895 rows from database in PHP. When you use less memory your script will work a little faster.

Comment: Already i paginated my first query (its about 0.1 second) but i want to fetch all brands to show user to filter them . ( And on it i cant limit or paginate the query)